# More performant Windows Explorer when accessing remote servers

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-management

Using Windows Explorer to access Remote servers is horridly slow. It must be making a million hops, particularly when multiple files are simultaneously selected.

I sometimes resort to the command line but that's only because the performance sucks in teh GUI.

Is there a GUI that is better performing\wiser about limiting hops? I'm assuming that that is the main culprit beside the general network config.

I'm not looking for more bells and whistles. I'm looking for meat and potatos delivered faster.

Comment: What protocol are you using to access the remote servers?  FTP? SFTP? Samba file shares?

Comment: Give a try to file managers? Like [Far Manager](http://www.farmanager.com/) (it is free) or Total commander, XYPlorer and so on?